# Google Drive API - Mimic deleted file by replicating its fileId

Tags: r, google-drive-api, httr

I'm using the R httr package and the Google Drive API. Is there anything in the Google Drive API to set the `fileId` of a file?

The scenario is: I have a Tableau report that is looking at a Google Sheet. I can't stream new data into the sheet from R because it's too heavy on the API and I get HTTP errors even with long sleep times. I can't upload a new file because the automation would break; Tableau hooks into a file through its unique ID.

Any way I can get around this?

Comment: not clear how settings file ids would help. and you don't show the code that fails. unlikely the api will fail if you properly take care of per-second rates.

Answer (score 1):

File id is set by google drive when you insert the file. Its not something you can supply.

The closes thing is in v3 which has something called [genreatedids](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/generateIds) but this again is an ID created for you by Google its not one you can supply.

I can think of no work around for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy lemon squeezy.

In Google Drive, the "file" (the thing with the ID) is a separate entity from that file's "content". So it's very simple to completely replace the content of an existing file without creating a new file. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update . If the files are large, make sure you use the `resumable upload` form of the API as described here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable